# Radgrid sub-grid data not showing up

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to add sub-grid to a grid. Right now I see the arrow to the left of the main-grid's row, and when clicked it shows me the sub-grid with all the columns, however it says there is no data for rows.

In the debugger I see the data is bound on server side by API assigned as OnDetailTableDataBind.

```
<telerik:RadGrid
 ...
OnDetailTableDataBind="myfunction"
...
```

In the function I'm binding data like so:

```
protected void myfunction(object source, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    e.DetailTableView.DataSource = SubGridData;
}
```

Checked in debugger that the values are set in the SubGridDetailTable, it has some test data in it for now.

I copied the detail tables section from another program, so it should be OK, is there something I can look out for? why isn't the data from sub-grid not get displayed?  I looked for a grid.DataBind(), but it doesn't look like the other program calls it for sub-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you have some relational constraint between the Parent and Child tables? If you haven't yet, check for a `<ParentTableRelation>` tag.  Also, since you're using test data, make sure that the columns correspond to the data in the parent grid.